# What is the easiest way in pure Perl to stream from another HTTP resource?

Tags: perl, http, streaming, mod-perl

What is the easiest way (without opening a shell to curl and reading from stdin) in Perl to stream from another HTTP resource? I'm assuming here that the HTTP resource I'm reading from is a potentially infinite stream (or just really, really long)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTTP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Lite)'s `request` method allows you to specify a callback.

> The `$data_callback` parameter, if used, is a way to filter the data as it is received or to handle large transfers. It must be a function reference, and will be passed: a reference to the instance of the http request making the callback, a reference to the current block of data about to be added to the body, and the `$cbargs` parameter (which may be anything). It must return either a reference to the data to add to the body of the document, or undef.

<s>However, looking at the source, there *seems* to be a bug in `sub request` in that it *seems* to ignore the passed callback.</s> It *seems* safer to use `set_callback`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Lite;

my $http = HTTP::Lite->new;
$http->set_callback(\&process_http_stream);
$http->http11_mode(1);

$http->request('http://www.example.com/');

sub process_http_stream {
    my ($self, $phase, $dataref, $cbargs) = @_;
    warn $phase, "\n";
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> ht
connect
content-length
done-headers
content
content-done
data
done
```

It looks like a callback passed to the `request` method is treated differently:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Lite;

my $http = HTTP::Lite->new;
$http->http11_mode(1);

my $count = 0;
$http->request('http://www.example.com/',
    \&process_http_stream,
    \$count,
);

sub process_http_stream {
    my ($self, $data, $times) = @_;
    ++$$times;
    print "$$times====\n$$data\n===\n";
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that would seem to explain why no matter what I was doing the documents I was returning were 0 bytes.

Comment: **Sigh** it seems that a callback function given to `request` is treated differently than one that is set using `set_callback` and the docs don't explain this correctly.

Comment: LWP has a callback mechanism too.

Answer (score 9):

Good old LWP allows you to process the result  as a stream.

E.g., here's a callback to yourFunc, reading/passing byte_count bytes to each call to yourFunc (you can drop that param if you don't care how large the data is to each call, and just want to process the stream as fast as possible):

```
use LWP;
...
$browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$response = $browser->get($url, 
                          ':content_cb' => \&yourFunc, 
                          ':read_size_hint' => byte_count,);
...
sub yourFunc {
   my($data, $response) = @_;
   # do your magic with $data
   # $respose will be a response object created once/if get() returns
}
```

Comment: +1, this may have worked, I didn't get a chance to try it as the other answer worked before I had a chance to implement this.

Comment: Hah, I *knew* it! I just couldn't find it in the docs so I erased my half-assed answer :)

Comment: @Ether I did not remember this either but note that `LWP` and `LWP::Simple` are different beasts.

Answer (score 3):

Wait, I don't understand.  Why are you ruling out a separate process? This:

```
open my $stream, "-|", "curl $url" or die;
while(<$stream>) { ... }
```

sure looks like the "easiest way" to me.  It's certainly easier than the other suggestions here...

Comment: I am not sure about this but won't this block until curl has read the complete response?

Comment: No, curl spits output out as it gets it; it doesn't buffer anything in memory.  You can verify yourself by grabbing a large file and watching the process size of curl as it loads.

Comment: Prefer not to create the threads, but otherwise, it's a fine solution.

Comment: Unless you have multiple gigabits of bandwidth available on your box, you will **always** be I/O limited when pulling from network resources.  The CPU work involved in spawning a process is unmeasurable noise.  I strongly suspect you're prematurely optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

[Event::Lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Event::Lib) will give you an easy interface to the fastest asynchronous IO method for your platform.

[IO::Lambda](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Lambda) is also quite nice for creating fast, responsive, IO applications.

Comment: I didn't know about that module. It looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version I ended up using via Net::HTTP

This is basically a copy of the example from the Net::HTTP man page / perl doc

```
use Net::HTTP;

my $s = Net::HTTP->new(Host => "www.example.com") || die $@;
$s->write_request(GET => "/somestreamingdatasource.mp3");
my ($code, $mess, %h) = $s->read_response_headers;
while (1) {
  my $buf;
  my $n = $s->read_entity_body($buf, 4096);
  die "read failed: $!" unless defined $n;
  last unless $n;
  print STDERR "got $n bytes\n";
  print STDOUT $buf;
}
```