# Are there any HTTP connection iterators in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, iterator, lwp

I'm trying to parse results from queries over HTTP that can return up to millions of lines - where each line need to be parsed. Ideally I would love to read a line at a time from a connection and parse it as I go - so basically a FileHandle-esque iterator, but the existing HTTP libraries all seem to fetch all content at once, although one can a) save to a file, or b) process chunks using a code ref. A is not ideal as it is a two-pass solution (the file would need to be read line by line after the data is transmitted, and it would take up storage, perhaps unnecessarily). B is not ideal as would like to be able to return each line, rather than handle it in a code ref, and moreover a chunk is not a line, so that LWP solution does not benefit from LWP line reconstitution. I know there are non-blocking solutions (using AnyEvent and Coro) but these seem more interested in non-blocking-ness rather than line-by-line processing. Can anyone point me in a good direction here, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback lets you do anything that you want. You could make it so you buffer the input as you get it and read lines from the buffer. Perl lets you open filehandles on just about anything (using `tie`), including strings (with `open`). Anything else you might find is ultimately going to receive a chunk and turn it into lines anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - regarding the strategy of feeding into a buffer from the callback and reading it out from the accessor, what is to stop this i) from consuming lots of memory if processing is slower than reading from the connection ii) erroneously returning empty lines/appearing to have reached the end of the buffer if the parsing gets ahead of reading from the connection?

Comment: @flightlessbird: i) Nothing, but that's extremely unlikely for any but the most complex processing because CPUs are several orders of magnitude faster than network communications. ii) Unless you've written your own buffer-handling code and done it incorrectly, reads from the buffer will block when the buffer is empty rather than returning empty lines or EOF.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply @Dave. So to recap, the best way forwards is appending to a sting buffer, which is opened to a filehandle for reading - each read line will block until data is appended to it from the connection. That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the accepted answer on [What is the easiest way in pure Perl to stream from another HTTP resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567895/what-is-the-easiest-way-in-pure-perl-to-stream-from-another-http-resource)  I haven't used HTTP::Lite myself, but it appears that it supports callback-based handling of received data, so that should work for you.